# LuaSockets and Code::Blocks

Tags: sockets, lua, codeblocks

I have Lua incorporated on code:blocks IDE and I want to do some TCP programming with a Lua library called LuaSockets. The problem is I cant install it and have no idea how to do it (I already searched everywhere for a long time, god knows how much) Is there anyone that has already done this?

Comment: Are you trying to write Lua script code that calls LuaSocket functions, or are you trying to write C/C++ code that modifies the LuaSocket library?

Comment: im trying to write a lua script that calls luaSocket functions

Answer (score 1):

Install [luarocks](http://luarocks.org/) according to the instructions for [Windows](http://luarocks.org/en/Installation_instructions_for_Windows) or [UNIX](http://luarocks.org/en/Installation_instructions_for_Unix)

From a command line, type

```
luarocks install luasocket
```